# How to use MathJax in designMode on iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, css, math

I am creating a math input application with a designMode on iFrame, and I've decided to use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) for the equations. The problem is, it wouldn't seem to change the content in my designMode on iframe, so is there a way to overcome that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do not you set the `designMode='on'` dynamically in JS.

```
var iframe = $('iframe')[0],
  iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
  iframeDoc.designMode = "on";
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/Vhv5F/

Comment: I think your problem was that mathjax was not working in case you have design Mode on? Share some of your code to get me some clarification about your issue.

Comment: No it is working, its just when I use the refresh statement for mathjax (`MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);`), it wouldn't apply to my iframe.

Comment: When do you try to apply the above code? Would you mind sharing the code?

Comment: I type LaTeX code into the iframe, and I press a button, and it should automatically use the code on top to update.

Comment: Be sure that you load MathJax and run it in the iframe, not the parent frame.  Your Typeset call has to be performed from within the iframe, and you have to have loaded MathJax.js into the iframe to allow that.